# ASP.NET Core Web API and OpenIddict

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I'm trying to use `OpenIddict` to my `asp.net core web api` project. I have followed the instructions written [here](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) but when i try to build the project i get the following error

> Unable to resolve 'OpenIddict.Mvc (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.

I have created the project through Visual Studio 2017 (I suppose i have the latest .NET Core tooling installed by default). Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
The 1st step of the instructions says that you have to update your packages to reference the ASP.NET Core RTM packages. What that means?

And my .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation" Version="$(AspNetContribOpenIdExtensionsVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="$(OpenIddictVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="$(OpenIddictVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="$(OpenIddictVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\iBoard.Repositories\iBoard.Repositories.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have also tried with `Version="1.0.0-*"`

Comment: Are you sure you've added the MyGet feed to your packages sources, as indicated in the README?

Comment: @Pinpoint yes..i have created the NuGet.config file in the root folder of my application and added the required references.

Comment: Have you tried to restart VS to ensure the new feed is correctly taken into account?

Comment: Yesbut still no luck

Comment: Can you please share your .csproj file?

Comment: Where are the `$(OpenIddictVersion)` and `$(AspNetContribOpenIdExtensionsVersion)` properties defined? I don't see them in your .csproj.

Comment: @Pinpoint problem solved...it was a combination of your suggestions. At first i was trying with Version="1.0.0.-*" but without prior restart of VS and when i did the restart i used the variables but i forgot to import the file with the declarations. So please post your comment as an answer in order to accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the missing `OpenIddictVersion`/`AspNetContribOpenIdExtensionsVersion` properties in your .csproj and it should work:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetContribOpenIdExtensionsVersion>1.0.0-*</AspNetContribOpenIdExtensionsVersion>
    <OpenIddictVersion>1.0.0-*</OpenIddictVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Alternatively, you can also directly hardcode the right version:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation" Version="1.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="1.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="1.0.0-*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```